# How to solve "Duplicate Of Template Name"?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, theme, setup-upgrade

When I installed a new module and did the `setup:upgrade` I received this message:

[image: Duplicate Of Template Name on Magento 2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Probably the issue is on **database**, so open the table `setup_module` and complete the module that doesn't have `data_version` completed.

[image: Duplicate Of Template Name on Magento 2]

Answer (score 8):

Duplicate of Template name comes from the module-email
So setup:upgrade tries to add e-mail templates that already exist. Remove any non altered templates from the database.

Comment: This is a correct answer. Setup version is just a consequence of this.

Comment: For me it was Temando_Shipping, it was trying to add Emails here so I was able to track down exact emails that I have to remove
\Temando\Shipping\Setup\SetupData::addPickupOrderEmailTemplate
\Temando\Shipping\Setup\SetupData::addPickupOrderGuestEmailTemplate

Comment: same Temado problem for me /vendor/temando/module-shipping-m2/Setup/UpgradeData.php just comment the 2 addPickup calls as @Macas said

Comment: @open-ecommerce.org you can either remove one those methods or remove emails from database. Ofc if you chose to remove methos - after you finish your setup upgrade, do not forget to return them back.

Comment: This  should  be the  accepted  answer

Answer (score 2):

hey i had the same problem , Remko de Keijzer is right here , the problem is any module is trying to add email template that already exist , to solve this

1. open your database
2. RUN `SELECT * FROM email_template`
3. Here in the `template_code` column and `orig_template_code`  you will find the duplicate template id . You just have to remove that row from the table.
4. To find which one is  duplicate go to Setup/InstallData.php file of the problematic  module , like in the above example error comes immediately below Amasty_Rma so it is  problematic.

Hope this saves your time